# is it possible? passing address of local static value to main pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, static

```
#include<stdio.h>

void f(int *p) {
    static int data = 5;
    p=&data;
}

int main(void) {
    int *ip=NULL;
    f(ip);
    printf("%d\n", *ip);
    return 0;
}
```

if it is possible. 
what is cause error?
how can I fix the code?

Comment: `p` is a copy of `ip`, if you change `p` you do not change `ip`.

Comment: pardon the obvious, but wouldn't that otherwise useless `void` return result from `f` be better spent returning the address rather than using a parameter in the first place ?

Comment: This has been asked soo many times already, a standard answer for this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this way you end up changing the value of a local pointer, you need to pass a pointer to pointer (`&`) from `main` and use the dereference operator (`*`) in the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int **p) {
    static int data = 5;

    *p = &data;
}

int main(void) {
    int *ip = NULL;

    f(&ip);
    printf("%d\n", *ip);
    return 0;
}
```

But usually we prefer to work with the same level of indirection returning the address from the function, this is easier to read (at least for me):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *f(void) {
    static int data = 5;

    return &data;
}

int main(void) {
    int *ip = f();

    printf("%d\n", *ip);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a pointer to the pointer to change the value of the actual pointer:

```
void some_fun(int **p)
{ 
    static int i = 10;
    *p = &i;
}
```

That being said, it is not necessarily advisable to do that. The only direct use I could think of is to delay the execution of the initialization of a global until its first use.